# How to make the ribbon control quick access toolbar be on the top of my GUI?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, ribbon-control

How to make the ribbon control quick access toolbar be on the top of my GUI?

[image]

So I need the quick access toolbar to appear on top as it does in windows apps such as
word and outlook.

Edit: This is my newest code after feedback from other people here:

```
<r:RibbonWindow
    x:Class="Company.RouteVisualization.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
    Title="Route Visualization"
    Height="395"
    Width="832"
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
    WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <r:Ribbon Grid.Row="0" Name="ribbon">
            <r:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
                <r:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <r:RibbonButton Label="B1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <r:RibbonButton Label="B2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </r:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
            </r:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
            <r:RibbonTab Header="Home">
                <r:RibbonGroup Name="groupHome" Header="View">
                    <r:RibbonToggleButton Name="DisplayMapButton" Label="Display Map" IsChecked="True"
                    LargeImageSource="../Resources/Images/Earth.png" 
                    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
                    <r:RibbonToggleButton Name="OnlineButton" Label="Online"    
                    LargeImageSource="../Resources/Images/Online.png"     
                    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
                </r:RibbonGroup>
            </r:RibbonTab>
        </r:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</r:RibbonWindow>
```

Comment: you can set `WindowStyle=None` in you window tag in xaml, but this will also won't show the controlBox (Maximize, minimize and close buttons) ...

Comment: Nope that is not what I need. I need the max, min and close buttons :)

Comment: You could just do what Omribitan says, and just create your control buttons. (That's what I've had to do on one of my own projects).

Comment: Then what @Sam said is the way to go ...

Comment: Sorry, i've misunderstood your question. I thought you were talking about the space at the very top of the window.lol

Comment: Well yeah! Why did you delete your answer?! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a RibbonWindow, you can check the following link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/04/why-should-i-use-a-ribbonwindow.aspx

Also read this:

http://www.shujaat.net/2012/10/ribbon-quick-access-toolbar.html

[image: Ribbon sample]

Comment: So I just change that one thing, inherit from RibbonWindow and not from Window? That is all?

Comment: Yes, but make sure to make the changes in both .xaml and .cs

Comment: I did as you said, but all that happened is the minimize, maximize and close buttons disappeared and the top remained.

Comment: Can you post your xaml code of the window that is using the ribbon, or a small example for reproduction?

Comment: Is this not what you have wanted according to your sample, or it appears differently on your computer?

Comment: But the minimize, maximize and close buttons are gone.

Comment: Then you should remove the WindowStyle property because it is set to None.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37591/discussion-between-chevul-ervin-and-user2381422)